# Give Author users the right to embed

Tags: author, embed, iframe

I'm trying to allow "author" users to embed in posts. I (the administrator) can iframe, embed, etc...., but authors can not.

Can someone show me to give authors 'just' the ability to embed and iframe in posts?

Comment: I have a similar issue where administrators code is stripped like iframe code for youtube or google maps, however Super Admin is not. I don't see any plugins doing this and it is not what I see as normal behaviour. There is no code in functions either..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The capability you are after is called `unfiltered_html`. Some options:

1. Modify **author** capabilities in your theme `functions.php`. This is saved in the DB, so you can access a page, make sure it works then remove it from your `functions.php` file. A better option would be to run it on theme activation. See [this page on WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap) for options:

   ```
   function add_theme_caps() {
       // gets the author role
       $role = get_role( 'author' );

       // This only works, because it accesses the class instance.
       // would allow the author to edit others' posts for current theme only
       $role->add_cap( 'unfiltered_html' ); 
   }
   add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');
   ```
2. Use a plugin that allows you to modify it using a UI, like [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/).

Comment: Thank you @oliver! FYI for anyone else. Add 'Unfiltered html' in user role editor to give rights to add embed and iFrame to posts.

Comment: I'm not sure this gives authors **just** the "ability to embed and iframe in posts" as requested. I am pretty sure it gives authors a lot more power than that, including the ability to edit posts written by other authors (which seems like a bad idea).

Comment: @s_ha_dum you're right, I make a mistake while copy pasting code and I've edited my post with the proper capability (unfiltered_html).

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad idea and you might as well just give those users "higher" roles as with the "unfiltered_html" permission it is not very hard to duplicate the admin authorization cookies and take control of the site.

What you should do is to teach them to use the built-in functionality of [oEmbed](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds), which should be enough to embed content from many sites in a simple way, by just putting the url of the content on a line of its own, but if that is not good enough, then you need to write shortcodes that will do the actual embed into the content.